# How to view different images on one activity layout by clicking on 5 different buttons

Tags: android, android-activity, imageview

I have two activity layout in Android Studio project one is main_activity and second is imageview_activity. Main_activity have 5 buttons for 5 images which store in drawable. how to code it when i click on button it show image on imageview layout. 5 different images on one layout imageview_layout.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the ID of the drawable from your main activity to imageview_activity through the intent. And then display image in your second activity based on the ID received.

**MainActivity**

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
 if(v.getId==R.id.img1)
 {
   startActivity(new Intent(this,ImageViewActivity.class).putExtra("id",1));
 }
 //similary for other Buttons
}
```

**ImageViewActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle b)
{
 //other code


 Bundle b2=getIntent().getExtras();
 if(b2!=null)
 {
   showImage(b2.getInt("id"));// Implement showImage to display image in an ImageView.
 }
}
```

Comment: ...\ImageViewActivity.java
Error:(24, 13) error: cannot find symbol method showImage(int)
...\MainActivity.java
Error:(91, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable getID
Error:(93, 67) error: cannot find symbol method putInt(String,int)